# I can't make my program to do any operation in JS (sum, multiplication, division, substraction) in a calculator

Tags: javascript, html, css

***Hello fellow coders!*** This is my first question at **Stack Overflow**.

I'm learning **JS** along with **HTML** and **CSS**, and right now I'm struggling with a simple code. It is basically a calculator which **sums, substracts, multiplies and divides**. Then, it shows an answer.

The thing is that **I can't render the result in the HTML file**, and I've already checked if everything is safe and sound, and I can't find the error in my code.

Please, if someone can help me, I would be delighted.
Much obliged!

```js
let num1 = 4;
let num2 = 4;
document.getElementById("num1-el").textContent = num1;
document.getElementById("num2-el").textContent = num2;
let opEl = document.getElementById("result-El");

function add() {
  let result = num1 + num2;
  opEl.textContent = "Sum: " + result;
}

function substract() {
  let result = num1 - num2;
  opEl.textContent = "Substract: " + result;
}

function division() {
  let result = num1 / num2;
  opEl.textContent = "Division: " + result;
}

function multiplication() {
  let result = num1 * num2;
  opEl.textContent = "Multiplication: " + result;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 50px;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Satoshi', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, white, rgb(182, 229, 245))
}

.box {
  background-color: white;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 35px;
  align-items: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 25px;
  box-shadow: .1rem .1rem 1.8rem rgb(68, 104, 140);
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-color: transparent;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 20px;
}

.parent {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: .5rem .5rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-left: 12px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
  width: 90px;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: .1rem .1rem 1.8rem rgb(68, 104, 140);
}

button {
  width: 110px;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
  border-color: transparent;
  font-family: 'Satoshi';
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 7px;
  margin-top: 0%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: .1rem .1rem 1.7rem rgb(68, 104, 140);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="calc.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      <span id="num1-el"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <span id="num2-el"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br>
  <br>

  <button onclick="add()">Add</button>
  <button onclick="substract()">Subs</button>

  <br>
  <br>

  <button onclick="division()">Div</button>
  <button onclick="multiplication()">Mult</button>

  <br>
  <br>

  <div class="box">
    <span id="result-el"></span>
  </div>

  <script src="calc.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: the error message is quite clear `opEl is null` - looks like a simple typographical error

Answer (score 1):

You have a capitalization error. HTML IDs are case-sensitive, so you'd either need to use `result-el` or `result-El` for both instances.